# When can you respecialize your hero?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

One of the buttons at the top of the main hero page is labeled "Respecialize" and the mouseover indicates that it allows you to redistribute the ability points on your hero.  However, I have yet to see the button enabled.  What triggers the ability to respecialize your hero?

Answer (score 6):

You can respecialise once you have 250 points in blood or tears.

Comment: Can you do it again when you reach the second level of Blood/Tears points?  So essentially, whenever you change classes?

Comment: Is it part of the change class process, or can you do it every 250 reputation points?  Or is it always active once you gain a new class?

Comment: It seems you can respec only once in campagen.

Comment: I thought you can only respec in non-campaign mode...