# How do you reset your traits (might, magic abilities)?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When can you respecialize your hero?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32739/when-can-you-respecialize-your-hero)

I know you reset the traits from the multiplayer by clicking the respecialize, but how do you reset the ones from the campaign?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot officially respec in a campaign, but there is a bug that will allow you to do so. When you level up a blood or tears rank (see the cutscene etc), for that turn only you can respec (you may have to choose magic tab for it to light up).